# Using lists of entities in Google App Engine Datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I am using objectify with Google App Engine (backed by their datastore project).  I am a little confused on how lists of entities work.

I have some **Student** entities, and I have some **Teacher** entities.

I want the **Teacher** to have a *students* property that is List of **Student** entities.

It seems easy and it seems to work ok.  However, I just noticed today that when I modify a property of a **Student**, it doesn't seems to update the **Student** in the various **Teacher**'s *students* List.  For example, if I change a student's name and save it, the student list from a teacher will still have its old name.  It is almost as if the teacher has its own local version of that object.

Is that correct?  Is there any way that I can get the actual object stored?  Or do I have to do something like just store the IDs?

Any help would be appreciated.

Here are the classes, for reference:

```
@Entity
@Index
public class StudentObj {
    @Id public Long id;
    public String StudentName;
}

@Entity
@Index
public class TeacherObj {
    @Id public Long id;
    public String TeacherName;
    public List<StudentObj> students;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should store the keys.

Comment: You mean, a list of keys instead of objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `List<Student>`, you are embedding the student data in the teacher object. To create a link to an independent entity, store a `List<Key<Student>>` or a `List<Ref<Student>>` in your teacher.